# app.run запущен python

Tags: python, flask, app

Как сделать действие в Flask например:

```
print("Запуск FLASK")
app.run()
print("FLASK Запущен")
```

app.run() бесконечный цикл, и там нельзя сделат действия после. Пробовал idle не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете поместить необходимые действия в функцию и вызвать ее перед запуском `app.run()`. Таким образом, функция `some_function()` будет выполнена перед запуском сервера `Flask`, а строка `print("FLASK Запущен")` будет выведена только после остановки сервера.

```python
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def some_function():
    print("Запуск FLASK")

some_function()
app.run()
print("FLASK Запущен")
```

Так же Вы можете попробовать использовать модуль `threading`. В этом примере `Flask` запускается в отдельном потоке, а основной поток ждет 10 секунд, затем продолжает выполнение и выводит `print("FLASK Запущен")`. По завершении работы основного потока, вызывается `flask_thread.join()`, чтобы дождаться остановки веб-приложения.

```python
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def run_flask():
    print("Запуск FLASK")
    app.run()

# Запуск Flask в отдельном потоке
flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_flask)
flask_thread.start()

# Продолжение выполнения программы в основном потоке
time.sleep(10)
print("FLASK Запущен")

# Остановка Flask
flask_thread.join()
```